# Which one could guarantee more precise delay duration? `nanosleep` or `select`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, select, kernel, sleep

Which one could guarantee more precise delay duration? `nanosleep` or `select`?Their input arguments are same type (`struct timeval`).
Could anybody help to make it clearly for me?I hope to know the internal mechanism.

Comment: The argument to `sleep()` is in seconds, `select()` allows fractions.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the clarification.But, maybe, i do not think it is the key point. If so, which one is better? `select` or `nanosleep`?

Comment: `nanosleep()` didn't exist when the documentation you refer to was written.

Comment: `select()` is primarily for waiting for input on multiple descriptors. Using it for fine-grained sleeping was just a workaround when there was no better method.

Comment: Why do you think one would be more precise than the other? I'm sure the kernel uses the same mechanism for both of them.

Comment: And unless you're using a real-time OS, there are no guarantees of precise timing anyway.

Comment: @Barmar Yea, I am developing applications in RTOS.So the precision is important for me.

Comment: I still doubt that it matters. Use `nanosleep()` for sleeping, use `select()` for waiting on descriptors.

Comment: @ I see.It's clear to me.Thank you for your attention.Hope you have a nice day!